# How to include per Project Jar file with xsbt-web-plugin / merge application.conf?

Tags: scala, sbt, war, xsbt-web-plugin

I just switched from maven to sbt for a Scala build. Since part of the builds are also war files, I use xsbt-web-plugin to create war files with sbt. Everything works fine, except an issue with the outputted WAR.

The WAR `dependsOn` two other sub projects (transitively). When I run package the classes and resources of the other sub projects are both merged and copied. Which also means that the `application.conf` is overwritten by the most recently defined `dependsOn` and not merged.

How this is solved by maven is that it includes every dependency as a JAR file in the `WEB-INF/lib`, however this is due to that maven has no mechanism like `dependsOn` vs `libraryDependencies`.

How can this be solved with xsbt-web-plugin? By using a merge strategy like OneJar or do I have to split the WAR build from the other build and define them as dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured it out with some more searching, https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/issues/111 gave the right hint.

Set `exportJars := true` for the `dependsOn` modules.